# Use Lottie animation in Android toolbar

Tags: android, kotlin, android-toolbar, lottie

Is it possible to add a lottie animation to an Android toolbar?

I attempted this:

```
override fun onCreateOptionsMenu(menu : Menu, inflater : MenuInflater) {
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_program_fragment, menu)
    val menuFavorite = menu.findItem(R.id.menuSubscribe)
    val lottieDrawable =  LottieDrawable()
    LottieComposition.Factory.fromAssetFileName(activity, "favorite.json", {
        composition ->
        lottieDrawable.setComposition(composition)
        lottieDrawable.loop(true)
        lottieDrawable.playAnimation()
        lottieDrawable.invalidateSelf()
        menuFavorite.icon = lottieDrawable
    })
}
```

This results in a `IllegalStateException: You or your view must set a Drawable.Callback before setting the composition.`

So I added a callback:

```
 lottieDrawable.callback = object : Drawable.Callback {
            override fun unscheduleDrawable(who: Drawable?, what: Runnable?) {
            }

            override fun invalidateDrawable(who: Drawable?) {
             }

            override fun scheduleDrawable(who: Drawable?, what: Runnable?, `when`: Long) {
            }

        }
```

Which stops the exception occurring but the icon is not drawn in the toolbar.

How do I make this work?

- Is the problem something to do with the intrinsic height of the `LottieDrawable`?
- What should the `Drawable.Callback` do (if anything)?
- Are there any implications for the `Fragment`/`Activity` lifecycle? I.e should I stop or cleanup something on destruction?

Comment: There is a more easy solution, https://stackoverflow.com/a/64017611/12805923

Answer (score 3):

I also had that doubt and I left my answer in case someone else needed it, I make this code and it works for me.

Create an attribute in the activity:

```
private LottieDrawable animateCameraIcon;
```

and put this code in your activity ***protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)***:

```
LottieTask<LottieComposition> task = LottieCompositionFactory.fromRawRes(this, R.raw.camera);

task.addListener(new LottieListener<LottieComposition>() {
    @Override
    public void onResult(LottieComposition result) {
        Log.i(TAG, "Loaded camera animation: "+result);
        animateCameraIcon = new LottieDrawable();
        animateCameraIcon.setComposition(result);
        animateCameraIcon.setRepeatCount(LottieDrawable.INFINITE);
        animateCameraIcon.setScale(0.23f);
        animateCameraIcon.playAnimation();
        animateCameraIcon.setSpeed(0.7f);
    }
});

task.addFailureListener(new LottieListener<Throwable>() {
   @Override
   public void onResult(Throwable result) {
      Log.e(TAG, "Error loading camera animation: "+result);
   }
});
```

And in the method ***public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu)*** make this:

```
if(animateCameraIcon != null){
  MenuItem cameraMenuItem =menu.getItem(0);
  cameraMenuItem.setIcon(animateCameraIcon);
}
```