# How to set Lottie file to menu item?

Tags: android, xml, menuitem, bottomnavigationview, lottie

I am creating a bottom navigation and the icon needs to be an animated Lottie file.
It seems it's not possible to write a binding adapter for the  tag. Is there any solution that allows us to have lottie animations in bottom nav?

```
<item
    android:id="@+id/my_navigation"
    android:icon="@drawable/my_icon"
    android:title="@string/my_text" 
    **app:setLottie=@raw/my_file/>**
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all create a custom layout, in this example name it layout_gift

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="30dp"
    android:layout_height="30dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <com.airbnb.lottie.LottieAnimationView
        android:id="@+id/watch_animation"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:lottie_autoPlay="true"
        app:lottie_fileName="gift.json"
        app:lottie_loop="true"
        app:lottie_speed="4" />

</LinearLayout>
```

then set it as;

```
    <item
    android:id="@+id/action_gift"
    android:orderInCategory="100"
    android:title="@string/gift"
    app:actionLayout="@layout/layout_gift"
    app:showAsAction="always" />
```

Moreover, clickListener is as below, you can't handle it in onOptionsItemSelected

```
 @Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
 
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.main, menu);

    MenuItem giftItem = menu.findItem(R.id.action_gift);
    View giftView = giftItem.getActionView();
    giftView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            // todo
        }
    });
}
```